# How to use regex to grab URLs and then echo URLs from website?

Tags: php, regex, url, echo

Just for fun, I'm trying to code something that will scan a website for YouTube URLs and save them. The URLs will not be within  tags so I need to use regex. I have that part down. But how I do go about echoing the URLs from an array?

What I have so far:

```
<?php

$website = file_get_contents('http://boards.4chan.org/mu/res/41283979');
$reg_exURL = "/(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?(?:.*?&(?:amp;)?)?v=|\.be/)([\w‌​\-]+)(?:&(?:amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?/";

if(preg_match($reg_exURL, $website, $urls)) {
    // Echo all values in the array
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        echo $url;
    }
} else {
    echo "No URLs Found.";
}

?>
```

But when I echo $url, I just get the word "Array". I want to see all the URLs, preferably one on each line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all urls from page (php)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128774/how-to-get-all-urls-from-page-php)

Comment: No it isn't because those answers rely on <a href=""> tags. I can't rely on such tags. I need a regex answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how 4chan adds `<wbr>` tags in the youtube IDs, probably as a security against things like this. You have to remove those tags from the source first with a replace.

Then you can use regex to match all links in the source, keeping in mind that a youtube video ID consists of letters, numbers, _, - and is always 11 characters long.

```
$website = str_replace("<wbr>","",file_get_contents('http://boards.4chan.org/mu/res/41283979'));

$regex = "/(https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[A-Za-z0-9_-]{11}/";
preg_match_all($regex , $website, $urls, PREG_SET_ORDER); 

foreach ($urls as $url)
    echo $url[0] . "<br>";
```

Comment: I had to replace your "<br>" with a "\n", but this worked perfectly and is exactly what I wanted. It also seems a lot more compact than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

`print_r` is used to output arrays:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: Using "print_r($url);" doesn't get any of the links I want. It seems to grab the very first link in an <a> tag.

Comment: correct - `$url` contains an array, so `echo` returns 'Array'

Comment: Update your regex, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717115/regular-expression-for-youtube-links

Comment: Thanks, that will come in handy for the future, but it doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `print_r($url)` or `var_dump($url)`. These are standard ways to print arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

```
<?php

$website = file_get_contents('http://boards.4chan.org/mu/res/41283979');
$reg_exURL = "/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?(?:.*?&(?:amp;)?)?v=|\.be\/)([\w‌​\-]+)(?:&(?:amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?/";
if(preg_match($reg_exURL, $website, $urls)) {
    // Echo all values in the array
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        echo $url;
    }
} else {
    echo "No URLs Found.";
}

?>
```

Comment: I updated the original post with your edits, but I'm still not getting anywhere. I added the URL I'm trying to scrape if it helps.

Comment: I didn't notice before, but it looks like there was an error in the regex. The forward slashes needed to be escaped. I've updated the answer with the working example.

Comment: For some reason, the URL that is echoed is "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHjNlHjN" when it should be echoing "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHjNmyzrVvM". Also, do you know how to echo the rest of the URLs on the page? I'm sorry for sounding so ignorant.